# sending base64 image to server through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, base64

I have build a image cropper tool from there i wanted to store that base64 image to server. I have sent it through Ajax. Image got stored in jpg format.But the problem is it's got corrupted. Can anyone suggest me what could be the solution?

Here is my ajax call :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'updateProfilePicture',
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {'image': encodeURIComponent(profileImageUrl)},
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```

Here is the controller for converting base64 to normal image and stored to server:

```
public function updateProfile(Request $request)
{
    $base64img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $request->Input(['image']));
    $data = base64_decode($base64img);
    $file = public_path() . '/users/' .'123123123.jpg';
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
    return \Response::json($data);
}
```

Comment: What does "corrupted" mean?

Comment: when i click on the image it says `we can't open this file`.

Comment: Why are you using different content types in client and server?

Comment: Are you sure you have base64 encoded the image, I dont see anything that suggests that you have

Comment: `profileImageUrl` is the base64 image URL

Comment: I am pretty sure you dont need to `encodeURIComponent()` a base64encoded string. Base64 encoded should be ok to travel over the wire without fiddling with it. Thats what it was invented for

Comment: After removed the encodeURIComponent it shows me `InvalidArgumentException Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` Error

Comment: @RiggsFolly — Base64 needs fiddling with to go into form encoded data because it can include + symbols … but you don't need `encodeURIComponent` because jQuery handles that for you.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the knowledge correction

Answer (score 3):

You aren't sending JSON so don't claim you are sending JSON. Remove this.

> ```
> contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
> ```

---

You are passing an object to `data`:

> ```
> data: {'image': encodeURIComponent(profileImageUrl)}
> ```

When you pass an object, jQuery will encode it as form URL encoded data.

By running your code through `encodeURIComponent` you cause the data to be **double** encoded.

Don't do that.

```
data: {'image': profileImageUrl }
```

Comment: After removed the `encodeURIComponent` it shows me `InvalidArgumentException
Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` Error

Comment: @Hola — Sounds like a problem with how the image data is being generated. You haven't shown us the input into the function though, so it is hard to tell.